# Excel IF "text" then number, IF another "text" then another number

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, statements

In column `B` I want a formula that says:

- If column `A` is Medium then use the value in `B2` which is `150,000`; if `A` is High then use the value in `B1` which is `300,000`; if `A` is Blank then use value in `B3` which `50,000`

I have bits of the formula but don't know how to include all in one formula.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A9),"50,000")
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You can do a if else structure, as in

```
=if(A9="Medium",$b$2,if(a9="High",$b$1,if(isblank(a9),B3,"")))
```

or a simpler index match:

```
=index($B$1:$B$3,match(A9,{"High","Medium",""},0))
```

Comment: Nice use of index! I've never used it before.

Comment: As an alternative to index, if you create a table with a column of your inputs ("High", "Medium", "") with a column of your outputs (150000, 300000, 50000), then `vlookup` is the function you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This formula assumes that anything other than "Medium" or "High" will show the value in B3:

```
=IF(A1="Medium",$B$2,IF(A1="High",$B$1,$B$3))
```

This formula handles values other than "Medium", "High", and blank, but you'll need to decide what to show if something other than those is in cell A1:

```
=IF(A1="Medium",$B$2,IF(A1="High",$B$1,IF(ISBLANK(A1),$B$3,"something else")))
```

Answer (score 0):

[IF INDEX SOLVED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAwUK.png)

```
B   C
```

15  MEDIUM  150000
16  HIGH    300000
17      50000
18          STATUS
19  JAVED   150000  MEDIUM
20  AHMED   300000  HIGH
21  KAMRAN  50000   0
22          INDEX(B$15:B$17,MATCH(C22,C$15:C$17,0))